# Spring filter and cookies

Tags: spring, cookies

I am facing issue while getting the cookie from subsequent request.

I have loginFilter where I am setting the cookie in response like below.

```
httpResponse.addCookie(new Cookie("TOKEN", "ABCXYSSSS"));
```

I can see both the cookies i.e JSESSIONID and TOKEN are avaiable in browser.

And when user access new request then I am getting only JSESSIONID in request, not getting TOKEN cookie in request

To get the cookie from repsonse

```
httpRequest.getCookies();
```

Could anybody provide me the input on this.

Comment: Could you provide us with some code, where do you add your cookie?

Comment: Once user successfully login  then I am setting the cookies to response like below.    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException  { HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request; httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;boolean flag = callToDB(username,pwd)
   if(flag)
   {
    httpResponse.addCookie(new Cookie("TOKEN", "ABCXYSSSS"));
   }